# Obtener datos de json_encode en petición AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

PHP

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($datos_query)){
 echo json_encode($row);
}
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "archivo.php",
data: "datos="+datos,
success: function(data)
    {   
    var datos = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(datos[0].timestamp);
    }
});
```

> console.log(data);

me retorna los valores en forma ["titulo", "texto", "contenido"]

> console.log(datos[0].timestamp);
>    me retorna undefined

Que estoy haciendo mal al obtener los datos? que me falta?

PD: al poner **dataType: 'json'** al AJAX me marca error

Comment: Vamos por partes, en primer lugar, ¿sabes por qué timestamp te da `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

Hay un problema en tu PHP:

Estás generando Json de cada fila que vas obteniendo y ésto genera un JSON inválido.

Para solucionarlo, revisa el siguiente código:

```
//Arreglo donde va a contener el resultado de la query.
$arregloDelResultado = array();

 WHILE($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos_query)){
    $arregloDelResultado[] = $row;    
 }

 //Ahora sí, finalmente que tienes el arregloDelResultado completo, a éste le das un formato JSON
 echo json_encode($arregloDelResultado);
```

Ahora tu AJAX, para leer los datos que hay en JSON, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var misDatosJSON =  [
  {
    "id": "5c662141b44915006533f26d",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "c29f0c86-798e-4a81-9b6c-040925c8b01f",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,003.36",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Randolph Rodriguez",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "KYAGORO",
    "email": "randolphrodriguez@kyagoro.com",
    "phone": "+1 (988) 475-3813",
    "address": "605 Sutton Street, Goodville, Massachusetts, 2881",
    "about": "Voluptate eiusmod pariatur voluptate Lorem nulla exercitation. Id cupidatat magna veniam culpa quis deserunt irure proident magna esse fugiat dolore. Esse sit nisi excepteur ea irure adipisicing eiusmod ex minim mollit ea velit voluptate. Ullamco irure ullamco veniam consectetur pariatur. Tempor ex ea sint sit deserunt id. Nostrud dolore fugiat et ut tempor adipisicing quis consectetur fugiat tempor tempor. In est duis esse sunt magna et nisi ut anim eiusmod id et.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-04-10T11:50:08 +07:00",
    "latitude": -86.477042,
    "longitude": -89.27628,
    "tags": [
      "sit",
      "nisi",
      "mollit",
      "veniam",
      "velit",
      "qui",
      "nisi"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Dickson Bentley"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Livingston Pruitt"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jaclyn Russell"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Randolph Rodriguez! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621413514ece26b88141e",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "30030aaa-e918-493d-a3c7-834705f51652",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,083.07",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 38,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Marisol Barlow",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "PAWNAGRA",
    "email": "marisolbarlow@pawnagra.com",
    "phone": "+1 (894) 486-2695",
    "address": "410 Malbone Street, Ruckersville, Georgia, 5898",
    "about": "Aliqua non esse est commodo ullamco eiusmod anim nostrud ea adipisicing enim fugiat. Nulla fugiat elit reprehenderit reprehenderit proident. Incididunt qui est mollit irure ea duis nisi labore in fugiat occaecat occaecat consectetur. Ad tempor laborum excepteur anim ipsum exercitation nulla. Et aliquip mollit consequat ad. Elit ea tempor commodo commodo ea deserunt voluptate nulla non nostrud aliqua veniam.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-03-10T02:12:43 +07:00",
    "latitude": -12.992765,
    "longitude": -109.547559,
    "tags": [
      "sint",
      "labore",
      "mollit",
      "magna",
      "aute",
      "enim",
      "adipisicing"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Monica Hays"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lesley Sparks"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Richardson Mcintosh"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Marisol Barlow! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621414f5788ddbbd625ea",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "9a8c0ae7-2410-49b2-b1b5-e9120803c100",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,197.73",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Tricia Boyd",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "KEGULAR",
    "email": "triciaboyd@kegular.com",
    "phone": "+1 (887) 410-2547",
    "address": "501 Bradford Street, Kent, New Mexico, 8088",
    "about": "Ullamco fugiat nisi esse ad pariatur amet consequat quis eiusmod minim quis. Anim nostrud amet veniam ullamco ipsum ad ut consectetur pariatur. Et officia ex nulla consectetur elit. Consectetur occaecat quis duis officia aliquip duis non enim cillum id non.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-10-06T03:15:53 +07:00",
    "latitude": 16.77847,
    "longitude": 4.794487,
    "tags": [
      "eiusmod",
      "aute",
      "aliquip",
      "enim",
      "irure",
      "est",
      "eiusmod"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 90,
        "name": "Gonzalez Witt"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Wooten Golden"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Natalia Brock"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Tricia Boyd! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621410df7cdb6ef509baf",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "88a410e5-ce5a-4f84-bc04-a0b38f2d6db4",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,989.32",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 37,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Maldonado Riddle",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "MOTOVATE",
    "email": "maldonadoriddle@motovate.com",
    "phone": "+1 (929) 575-3519",
    "address": "240 Noll Street, Robinson, South Carolina, 9212",
    "about": "Commodo aute ex Lorem voluptate consectetur quis aliqua tempor. Laboris anim qui incididunt enim velit fugiat qui irure. Dolor ea consectetur dolore dolore id id laboris excepteur. Anim tempor pariatur amet minim ad ullamco cupidatat eiusmod amet veniam sunt elit mollit cupidatat. Veniam eiusmod tempor do non excepteur velit aliquip laborum non id velit ad. Officia sint ex enim eiusmod elit aute occaecat laborum.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-10-05T04:57:52 +07:00",
    "latitude": -62.331829,
    "longitude": 157.055853,
    "tags": [
      "Lorem",
      "eiusmod",
      "aliquip",
      "anim",
      "dolor",
      "occaecat",
      "mollit"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Patsy Sweet"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Jennings Berg"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "White Mcclain"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Maldonado Riddle! You have 3 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c662141ba3d97af0998e9a4",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "ac508b64-8cce-464c-ad33-7351decfb177",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,244.12",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Bates Arnold",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ZILLA",
    "email": "batesarnold@zilla.com",
    "phone": "+1 (877) 544-3622",
    "address": "320 Garden Place, Itmann, Missouri, 1439",
    "about": "Sit dolore mollit tempor ad occaecat nisi sunt dolore dolore deserunt consequat magna reprehenderit ullamco. Eu fugiat proident adipisicing aliqua ex velit sunt in. Incididunt anim nostrud id Lorem nulla quis tempor sunt aliquip. Occaecat sint mollit cupidatat ex dolore laborum sint ipsum laborum nostrud. Officia aliqua velit dolor duis sint ad laborum qui do. Officia mollit do in pariatur ex pariatur labore officia. Irure excepteur in proident do ea ea fugiat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-03-25T02:36:07 +07:00",
    "latitude": -43.415912,
    "longitude": -10.406856,
    "tags": [
      "eiusmod",
      "incididunt",
      "duis",
      "aliquip",
      "officia",
      "adipisicing",
      "commodo"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Blanca Long"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Cathryn Williams"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Mckenzie Gilbert"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Bates Arnold! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621411abbefcd45dbc56e",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "b5331792-0e39-4b3d-9c40-5882f4b7f2ed",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,048.07",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Foreman Bell",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "YOGASM",
    "email": "foremanbell@yogasm.com",
    "phone": "+1 (979) 507-3435",
    "address": "494 Dakota Place, Makena, Louisiana, 4500",
    "about": "Quis sunt ullamco enim enim dolore adipisicing aliqua voluptate ad Lorem eiusmod. Minim occaecat aliqua pariatur culpa aliquip duis. Deserunt cillum sunt reprehenderit laboris ad esse magna anim ullamco aute nisi nisi qui. Aliquip anim mollit reprehenderit id esse nisi deserunt deserunt aliqua nisi id elit ipsum. Ea laboris commodo voluptate commodo occaecat sunt do tempor anim enim sit duis elit. Mollit tempor magna qui consequat aute amet sunt officia mollit ea nostrud ea nisi.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-03-20T11:17:25 +07:00",
    "latitude": -50.618937,
    "longitude": -76.141147,
    "tags": [
      "occaecat",
      "dolore",
      "magna",
      "do",
      "voluptate",
      "sit",
      "pariatur"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Iris Rollins"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Lindsey Perkins"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "Woodard Mercer"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Foreman Bell! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
];

$.each(misDatosJSON, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value.id );
  console.log("Hola usuario: " + value.name);
  console.log("Sus amigos son: ");
  $.each(value.friends, function(indiceAmigos, valorAmigos){
   console.log(indiceAmigos + ":  codigo: " +  valorAmigos.id + " "+ valorAmigos.name);
  })
  console.log("----------------");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```